# Show NSMenu only on NSStatusBarButton right click?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swiftui, appkit

I have the following code: (can be copy-pasted to New macOS project)

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var statusBarItem: NSStatusItem!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

        let statusBar = NSStatusBar.system
        statusBarItem = statusBar.statusItem(
            withLength: NSStatusItem.squareLength)
        statusBarItem.button?.title = ""

        // Setting action
        statusBarItem.button?.action = #selector(self.statusBarButtonClicked(sender:))
        statusBarItem.button?.sendAction(on: [.leftMouseUp])

        let statusBarMenu = NSMenu(title: "Status Bar Menu")
        statusBarMenu.addItem(
            withTitle: "Order an apple",
            action: #selector(AppDelegate.orderAnApple),
            keyEquivalent: "")

        statusBarMenu.addItem(
            withTitle: "Cancel apple order",
            action: #selector(AppDelegate.cancelAppleOrder),
            keyEquivalent: "")

        // Setting menu
        statusBarItem.menu = statusBarMenu
    }

    @objc func statusBarButtonClicked(sender: NSStatusBarButton) {
        let event = NSApp.currentEvent!

        if event.type ==  NSEvent.EventType.rightMouseUp {
            print("Right click!")
        } else {
            print("Left click!")
        }
    }

    @objc func orderAnApple() {
        print("Ordering a apple!")
    }


    @objc func cancelAppleOrder() {
        print("Canceling your order :(")
    }

}
```

**Actual behaviour**: Menu opens on both left and right click, statusBarButtonClicked is not triggered.
After removing this line:

```
statusBarItem.menu = statusBarMenu
```

statusBarButtonClicked triggers on left click, menu doesn't show up (as expected)

**Desired behaviour**: Menu opens on right click, on left click menu doesn't open, action is triggered.
 How do I achieve it?

### EDIT

I managed to achieve desired behavior with help of @red_menace comment:

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var statusBarItem: NSStatusItem!
    var menu: NSMenu!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

        let statusBar = NSStatusBar.system
        statusBarItem = statusBar.statusItem(
            withLength: NSStatusItem.squareLength)
        statusBarItem.button?.title = ""

        // Setting action
        statusBarItem.button?.action = #selector(self.statusBarButtonClicked(sender:))
        statusBarItem.button?.sendAction(on: [.leftMouseUp, .rightMouseUp])

        let statusBarMenu = NSMenu(title: "Status Bar Menu")
        statusBarMenu.addItem(
            withTitle: "Order an apple",
            action: #selector(AppDelegate.orderAnApple),
            keyEquivalent: "")

        statusBarMenu.addItem(
            withTitle: "Cancel apple order",
            action: #selector(AppDelegate.cancelAppleOrder),
            keyEquivalent: "")

        // Setting menu
        menu = statusBarMenu
    }

    @objc func statusBarButtonClicked(sender: NSStatusBarButton) {
        let event = NSApp.currentEvent!

        if event.type ==  NSEvent.EventType.rightMouseUp {
            statusBarItem.popUpMenu(menu)
        } else {
            print("Left click!")
        }
    }

    @objc func orderAnApple() {
        print("Ordering a apple!")
    }


    @objc func cancelAppleOrder() {
        print("Canceling your order :(")
    }

}
```

But Xcode says that `openMenu` func is deprecated in 10.14 and tells me to `Use the menu property instead`. Is there I way to achieve desired behaviour with new API?

Comment: Add `NSRightMouseUpMask` to `sendActionOn:`, and don't set the menu to the statusBarItem. Then just check the event in the action method and use `popUpStatusItemMenu:` to show the menu if the event is `NSEventTypeRightMouseUp`.  Note that several of these methods have been deprecated in Catalina.

Comment: @red_menace Thanks for answering :). You mean `popUpMenu:`? I can't find `popUpStatusItemMenu`. If so, popUpMenu works, but it's deprecated in 10.14. The warning reads 'use menu property instead'

Comment: Sorry, `popUpStatusItemMenu` is  Obj-C, Swift would be `popUpMenu`.  In Catalina, `popUpMenu` and `sendAction` are deprecated NSStatusMenu methods.  There is a `sendAction` method on NSButton, but the equivalent of `popUpMenu` would be something like set the status item menu and show it in the action method (e.g. via NSControl's `performClick`), then remove the menu when done so that it isn't used for the status item's normal behavior.  I don't know Swift well enough to provide a decent example.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The usual way a to show a menu is to assign a menu to the status item, where it will be shown when the status item button is clicked.  Since `popUpMenu` is deprecated, another way is needed to show the menu under different conditions.  If you want the right click to use an actual status item menu instead of just showing a contextual menu at the status item location, the status item menu property can be kept nil until you want to show it.

I've adapted your code to keep the `statusBarItem` and `statusBarMenu` references separate, only adding the menu to the status item in the clicked action method.  In the action method, once the menu is added, a normal click is performed on the status button to drop the menu.  Since the status item will then always show its menu when the button is clicked, an **NSMenuDelegate** method is added to set the menu property to `nil` when the menu is closed, restoring the original operation:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSMenuDelegate {
    // keep status item and menu separate
    var statusBarItem: NSStatusItem!
    var statusBarMenu: NSMenu!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let statusBar = NSStatusBar.system
        statusBarItem = statusBar.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.squareLength)
        statusBarItem.button?.title = ""

        statusBarItem.button?.action = #selector(self.statusBarButtonClicked(sender:))
        statusBarItem.button?.sendAction(on: [.leftMouseUp, .rightMouseUp])

        statusBarMenu = NSMenu(title: "Status Bar Menu")
        statusBarMenu.delegate = self
        statusBarMenu.addItem(
            withTitle: "Order an apple",
            action: #selector(AppDelegate.orderAnApple),
            keyEquivalent: "")
        statusBarMenu.addItem(
            withTitle: "Cancel apple order",
            action: #selector(AppDelegate.cancelAppleOrder),
            keyEquivalent: "")
    }

    @objc func statusBarButtonClicked(sender: NSStatusBarButton) {
        let event = NSApp.currentEvent!
        if event.type ==  NSEvent.EventType.rightMouseUp {
            print("Right click!")
            statusBarItem.menu = statusBarMenu // add menu to button...
            statusBarItem.button?.performClick(nil) // ...and click
        } else {
            print("Left click!")
        }
    }

    @objc func menuDidClose(_ menu: NSMenu) {
        statusBarItem.menu = nil // remove menu so button works as before
    }

    @objc func orderAnApple() {
        print("Ordering a apple!")
    }

    @objc func cancelAppleOrder() {
        print("Canceling your order :(")
    }

}
```

Comment: Your method does not work for me. The menu is only shown when I remove the line `statusBarItem.button?.performClick(nil)`. And the menu is then only shown when I right click the button twice. Do you know another method to show the menu without using `performClick(nil)`?

Comment: What exactly is "does not work" supposed to mean?  Do you get an error?  Is there something in the log?

Comment: Ok I know why it didn't work. I was using an external monitor and appearently when calling `performClick()` the click was performed on the external monitor instead of the built in of my laptop. Now I just need to find a way to perform the click on the correct monitor...

Comment: The click should be getting performed on the status button, wherever it is.

Comment: I think the problem in this case is that when using an external monitor there are two status buttons (one for each monitor). I will try to find a way to make this work and post a solution here if i got one.

Comment: Ok, so for anyone running into the same issue it seems like this is a bug in macOS Catalina: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/126072
Hopefully they will fix it soon.

Answer (score 5):

Here is possible approach. There might be more accurate calculations for menu position, including taking into account possible differences of `userInterfaceLayoutDirection`, but the idea remains the same - take possible events under manual control and make own decision about what to do on each event.

Important places commented in code. (Tested on Xcode 11.2, macOS 10.15)

```swift
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var statusBarItem: NSStatusItem!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

        let statusBar = NSStatusBar.system
        statusBarItem = statusBar.statusItem(
            withLength: NSStatusItem.squareLength)
        statusBarItem.button?.title = ""

        // Setting action
        statusBarItem.button?.action = #selector(self.statusBarButtonClicked(sender:))
        statusBarItem.button?.sendAction(on: [.leftMouseUp, .rightMouseUp]) // << send action in both cases

        let statusBarMenu = NSMenu(title: "Status Bar Menu")
        statusBarMenu.addItem(
            withTitle: "Order an apple",
            action: #selector(AppDelegate.orderAnApple),
            keyEquivalent: "")

        statusBarMenu.addItem(
            withTitle: "Cancel apple order",
            action: #selector(AppDelegate.cancelAppleOrder),
            keyEquivalent: "")

        // Setting menu
        statusBarItem.button?.menu = statusBarMenu // << store menu in button, not item
    }

    @objc func statusBarButtonClicked(sender: NSStatusBarButton) {
        let event = NSApp.currentEvent!

        if event.type ==  NSEvent.EventType.rightMouseUp {
            print("Right click!")
            if let button = statusBarItem.button { // << pop up menu programmatically
                button.menu?.popUp(positioning: nil, at: CGPoint(x: -1, y: button.bounds.maxY + 5), in: button)
            }
        } else {
            print("Left click!")
        }
    }

    @objc func orderAnApple() {
        print("Ordering a apple!")
    }


    @objc func cancelAppleOrder() {
        print("Canceling your order :(")
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. :) Just one more question.Why does the menu has top left and top right borders rounded? If I try to reposition it on y axis it just overlaps the menu bar. https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtTSY.png

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this code on macOS Catalina. 10.15.2. ( Xcode 11.3).
On left click It trigger action.
On right click it show menu.

```
//HEADER FILE
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@protocol MOSMainStatusBarDelegate

- (void) menuBarControllerStatusChanged: (BOOL) active;

@end


@interface MOSMainStatusBar : NSObject

@property (strong) NSMenu *menu;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSImage *image;
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) id<MOSMainStatusBarDelegate> delegate;

- (instancetype) initWithImage: (NSImage *) image menu: (NSMenu *) menu;
- (NSStatusBarButton *) statusItemView;
- (void) showStatusItem;
- (void) hideStatusItem;


@end

//IMPLEMANTION FILE. 

#import "MOSMainStatusBar.h"

@interface MOSMainStatusBar ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSStatusItem *statusItem;

@end

@implementation MOSMainStatusBar

- (instancetype) initWithImage: (NSImage *) image menu: (NSMenu *) menu {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.image = image;
        self.menu = menu;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) setImage: (NSImage *) image {
    _image = image;
    self.statusItem.button.image = image;

}

- (NSStatusBarButton *) statusItemView {
    return self.statusItem.button;
}

- (void) showStatusItem {
    if (!self.statusItem) {
        self.statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSSquareStatusItemLength];

        [self initStatusItem10];

    }
}

- (void) hideStatusItem {
    if (self.statusItem) {
        [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] removeStatusItem:self.statusItem];
        self.statusItem = nil;
    }
}



- (void) initStatusItem10 {

    self.statusItem.button.image = self.image;


    self.statusItem.button.imageScaling =  NSImageScaleAxesIndependently;

    self.statusItem.button.appearsDisabled = NO;
    self.statusItem.button.target = self;
    self.statusItem.button.action = @selector(leftClick10:);

    __unsafe_unretained MOSMainStatusBar *weakSelf = self;

    [NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:
     (NSEventMaskRightMouseDown | NSEventModifierFlagOption | NSEventMaskLeftMouseDown) handler:^(NSEvent *incomingEvent) {

         if (incomingEvent.type == NSEventTypeLeftMouseDown) {
             weakSelf.statusItem.menu = nil;
         }

         if (incomingEvent.type == NSEventTypeRightMouseDown || [incomingEvent modifierFlags] & NSEventModifierFlagOption) {

             weakSelf.statusItem.menu = weakSelf.menu;
         }

         return incomingEvent;
     }];
}

- (void)leftClick10:(id)sender {

    [self.delegate menuBarControllerStatusChanged:YES];
}
```

Comment: My knowledge of objc is event worse than knowledge of swift, but I can see that you are setting menu on right click and setting it to nil on left click. Honestly, it looks a little bit like dirty workaround to me, since NSMenu provides popUp function (Asperi's answer). But maybe your approach is considered OK in macos development. Am I wrong?

Comment: This is what I used (I got the basics from the web, and design it in my own class). If what you need is right click and left click, this is working code. I use it in my app for 10+ month, and never notice any problem. I don't see any "dirty" thing in this code. what I did not understand on the other answer is the position of menu . In my code I don't "touch" position = less future problems.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this code on Catalina. Rather than `performClick` like some of the other answers suggest, I had to manually position the popup. This works for me with external monitors.

```swift
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
        statusItem.button?.action = #selector(onClick)
        statusItem.button?.sendAction(on: [.leftMouseUp, .rightMouseUp])
        
        menu = NSMenu()
        menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Quit", action: #selector(NSApplication.terminate(_:)), keyEquivalent: "q"))
        menu.delegate = self
        
    }
    
    @objc func onClick(sender: NSStatusItem) {
        
        let event = NSApp.currentEvent!
       
        if event.type == NSEvent.EventType.rightMouseUp {
            // right click, show quit menu
            statusItem.menu = menu;
            menu.popUp(positioning: nil, 
                at: NSPoint(x: 0, y: statusItem.statusBar!.thickness),
                in: statusItem.button)
        } else {
           // main click 
        }
    }
    @objc func menuDidClose(_ menu: NSMenu) {
        // remove menu when closed so we can override left click behavior
        statusItem.menu = nil
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Learning from the great answers already given in here I came up with an alternative.

The advantage of this approach is that you only set the `NSMenu` once and don't have to juggle with setting it or removing it anymore.

#### Setting up the `NSStatusBarButton`

```swift
let status = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
status.button!.image = NSImage(named: "status")
status.button!.target = self
status.button!.action = #selector(triggerStatus)
status.button!.menu = /* your NSMenu */
status.button!.sendAction(on: [.leftMouseUp, .rightMouseUp])
```

#### Receiving the action

```swift
@objc private func triggerStatus(_ button: NSStatusBarButton) {
    guard let event = NSApp.currentEvent else { return }
        
    switch event.type {
    case .rightMouseUp:
        NSMenu.popUpContextMenu(button.menu!, with: event, for: button)
    case .leftMouseUp:
            /* show your Popup or any other action */
    default:
        break
    }
}
```