# (MacOS) How to get a pointer to an application's NSStatusItem

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am working in a system where I do not have reference to the application's NSStatusItem (or anything really). Is there a way to snag a reference to a previously created NSStatisItem? I can construct a new icon with `statusItemWithLength` but the associated menu and actions are lost.

A little bit of background, this is actually a Java application and there is currently no way to set a status icon to use Mac's template behavior. Previously we just changed the icon color manually, but BigSur doesn't throw an event when it decides to change the statusBar's color. I was going to attempt to set statusItem.button.image.template to true using native calls, but while prototyping in obj-c I ran into this issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: any apps statusIcon or (i assume you want) your own apps statusIcon?

Comment: @OlSen My own statusIcon.

Comment: How do you create your status item and where do you store it?

Comment: [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59635971/show-nsmenu-only-on-nsstatusbarbutton-right-click) should be helpful